# magento 1.9 - 'submit shipping' btn is not working on admin page!

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, shipment

Once an order is confirmed, i also confirm the shipment about that order.

So on Sales > order, i click the ship btn located in upper right side. Then, i write down the tracking code and submit the shipment!

btw it had been working well. Oneday i found that the the button of "submit shipping" is not working! 
[image]

**I checked the bug report on chrom,firefox even internet edge and log file as well. i can see nothing wrong so can i guess it would be frontend issue that the website didn't recognize this one as button? I didn't change any other javascript and configuration of extension tho.becuase it is the clone site of our website.**

Could you share what happened on my website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution for this question:

Problem resolved: Change the file: items.phtml

> app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\shipment\create\items.phtml

Change the function submitShipment to:

```
function submitShipment(btn) {
 var checkbox = $(btn).up('.order-totals').select('#create_shipping_label')[0];

 if (!validQtyItems()) {
        return;
    }
    disableElements('submit-button');
    $('edit_form').submit();    
}
```

Comment: @piyush Can you please tell what the error was?